# Mostrar un dropdown fuera del navbar-collapse de bootstrap con las mismas funciones responsive

Tags: bootstrap-3

Lo que se busca es que el icono de notificaciones nunca se colapse:

[image: Ejemplo de lo que se quiere lograr]

Si se intenta agregar con la clase `navbar-brand`, no funciona lo responsive:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#action-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tareas</a>
  <a class="navbar-brand">
    <notificaciones></notificaciones>
  </a>
```

[image: No se logra de esta forma]

Si se agrega de la forma de `navbar-nav` se muestra casi correcto, el problema es que crea un segundo renglón, sin lograr el resultado correcto:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <notificaciones></notificaciones>
</ul>
```

[image: Casi se logra]

Comment: ¿Probaste poniendo tu elemento de notificaciones dentro de un elemento con la clase `.navbar-text`?

Comment: Si, intenté ya varias formas de declarar el elemento, más que nada yo creo que con CSS se logra abrirle un espacio en la barra de navegación fuera del "collapse" pero no e tenido éxito.

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas que tenga la clase 'navbar-loquesea'? Si quieres que se mantenga dentro de la barra del menú pero sin que entre en el collapse basta con que sea un 'a' con cualquier otra clase que te crees para darle el estilo que deseas.